# ip to domain htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, ip

i cannot redirect my domain ip to the domain name, i have the following in my htaccess file which im told should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^37\.61\.233\.81
RewriteRule (.*) http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But thats not working, anyone got any idea why it isnt working? thanks for the help.

Edit
Full htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^37\.61\.233\.81
RewriteRule (.*) http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^jpcreativevision\.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/404.php
```

Comment: It should work, do you have `RewriteEngine On` before?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the message, yes RewriteEngine on is on.

Comment: What URL did you try to test it? Can you show full .htaccess?

Comment: If i go to 37.61.233.81 it comes up with the default web page where i want it to go to http://jpcreativevision.co.uk i can post as much of it as i can, will update the question.

Comment: Move both 301 rules up i.e. just below `RewriteEngine on` line.

Comment: Tried that, cleared cache didnt work, thanks for the help thought.

Comment: You're getting a different default page for `http://37.61.233.81/` which means request for `http://37.61.233.81/` is NOT even reaching about .htaccess

Comment: btw `http://www.jpcreativevision.co.uk` gets redirected to `http://jpcreativevision.co.uk` fine.

Comment: @anubhava not reaching it you say? that is strange thats what ie been told my ip for my domain is, do ii have to put the htaccess elsewhere other than the public_html?

Comment: No that is correct path since `non-www to www` is happening fine.

Comment: When you request by IP it using some `DocumentRoot` (can happen in shared hosting)

Comment: Ah i see, is their any way around it if your on shared hosting?

Comment: Unlikely as that IP is shared by so many domain names on that host.

Comment: thats for the help mate, i can pay extra to get my own ip so think i'll just do that.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes definitely thats the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it via http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it says, that your rule should work as expected.

However, you may try a different order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^37\.61\.233\.81
RewriteRule (.*) http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^jpcreativevision\.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/404.php
```

Comment: Yeah it should work, worked on other sites think i'll need to send out a few emails to my hosting company see if its anything on their end